# Can I update git on my OSX using homebrew without issue?

Tags: git, homebrew

If I install git using homebrew on OSX (Yosemite) will it conflict with my non-brew installation or will it simply update it?

I'm not sure if git was installed by default or if I installed it manually but I am a little nervous using homebrew if it will cause issues.

Is there a way for me to use homebrew safely for this?

Comment: It won't update it. It _should_ supersede it for all command-line use. There's a `PATH` environment variable that lists the places to look for installed code, in order, and it _should_ have brew's directories listed in front of the factory-install ones.  Command-line use has as much in the way of common-knowledge fundamentals as any GUI (e.g. `^R` is "incremental backward search through the command-line history" almost everywhere, and `PATH` and `HOME` are two of the most important environment variables) but the two systems, GUI/CLI, don't overlap much, or at all.

Answer (score 1):

Homebrew will not overwrite the version of git that ships with OS X (more specifically, I think it is installed as part of Xcode). That version of git is in `/usr` and Homebrew's is at `/usr/local`; Homebrew will not touch files outside of `/usr/local`. You will need to put `/usr/local/bin` in your `$PATH` *before* `/usr/bin` to use it by default in the shell, though.